# Mapping of Blob type in C++Driver

Tags: c++, cassandra

According to "datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/basics/",  the blob data type of Cassandra is matched to 'const cass_byte_t*'.  Suppose the database,  contains a structure saved in the form of blob; how can I fetch it. 
Somebody had suggested me using cass_value_get_bytes().  Can anybody give example of how to use this function to fetch the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with `cass_value_get_bytes()`? You simply need to perform casting of data read to your structure, something like:

```
const cass_byte_t* outPtr = null;
size_t outSize = 0;
if (cass_value_get_bytes(casValue, &outPtr, &outSize) == CASS_OK) {
   if (outSize == sizeof(YourStruct)) {
       const YourStruct* yourStruct = reinterpret_cast<const YourStruct*>(outPtr);
   }
}
```